# Can Debian recognize a second laptop HDD installed in a DVD drive bay?

Tags: debian, partition, hard-disk

I cannot find any companies selling 2.5" laptop HDDs larger than 1 TB, so I want to install a second 1 TB HDD by removing the DVD drive and mounting the drive using an aluminum caddy, such as one shown [here](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=hdd%20caddy&N=-1&isNodeId=1).

Is Debian able to recognize HDDs installed in this way? If I install partitions during the install process, such as `/` or `/usr/` to is, will it require that I manually mount them?

Comment: Why not? Though you might want to add /home or /var...or if you have LVM, extend partitions onto that disk.

Comment: Is there a reason to put `/home/` or `/var` onto the extra disk instead of on the regular disk drive? Is that drive likely to run slowly?

Comment: you can put anything  if you are willing to reinstall... it is easier to left things as they are and change over some partitions. or then doing some grub configurations.

Comment: FYI: Seagate at least makes 2TB, 3TB, and 4TB 2.5" drives. Seems like they make 5TB as well.

Answer (score 5):

Debian will be able to recognize them as the HDD they are, since the drive would report back that it is a block-based device whenever the system queries it. That shouldn't be a problem.

As for putting partitions on that drive, it depends on how you mean to put them on there. If you intend to put the `/` directory on your main drive and `/usr/` on the other drive, you'll be required to use an initial ramdisk (initrd) to ensure the system can still boot. Debian should be able to handle that for you, since I believe it creates an initrd by default anyway.

Answer (score 3):

That caddy is just a form-factor adapter. It makes the SATA HDD fit in the slot intended for a SATA optical drive. They're both just SATA drives to Linux, so it should work.

If you set up partitions in the installer, they'll be added to `/etc/fstab` which will automatically mount them. If you set them up after install, you can add them to `/etc/fstab` yourself, so they'll automatically mount.